# Spring Batch configuration error in processor

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I want to configure Spring Batch job, but I receive the following error, how can I solve it?

Error:
[image]

Reader:

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;

public class MoviesReader implements ItemReader<SearchResponseRO>, StepExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public SearchResponseRO read() throws Exception {
        return new SearchResponseRO();
    }
}
```

Processor:

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;

public class MoviesProcessor implements ItemProcessor<SearchResponseRO, Movie> {
    @Override
    public Movie process(SearchResponseRO searchResponseRO) throws Exception {
        return new Movie();
    }
}
```

What do I need to change in order to fix the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to specify a type for the `chunk` operation. In your case that would be `<SearchResponseRO, Movie>`.

```
return stepBuilderFactory.get("downloadStep").<SearchResponseRO, Movie>chunk(10)
  .reader(reader)
  .processor(processor)
  .....
```

Without the type, it defaults to `<Object, Object>`:

```
stepBuilderFactory.get("test").chunk(10)
        .reader(new ItemReader<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
                return null;
            }
        })
        .processor(new ItemProcessor<Object, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object process(Object o) throws Exception {
                return null;
            }
        })
        .writer(new ItemWriter<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void write(List<?> list) throws Exception {

            }
        })
        .build();
```

If you look at the definition of the `chunk` method, it accepts an `int`, but returns `SimpleStepBuilder<I, O>`. Because there is no way to actually provide the types for `I` and `O`, you have to essentially cast them to the values that you want. I believe that the `.<Type>` syntax is just convenience for the direct cast when chaining calls, so the following two things should be the same:

```
public void castGenericReturnType() {
    System.out.println(this.<Integer>genericReturn(1));
    System.out.println((Integer) genericReturn(1));
}

public <I> I genericReturn(Object objectToCast) {
    return (I) objectToCast;
}
```

Comment: I had refactored my configs and did not pay attention to  <~>.chunk  (It was obfuscated). Thanks to you I realized it has the wrong <I,O>.chunk  types.